# Visualize animal movement as chart in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a table with data of animal movements like this:

5 N
40 NW
10 SW
10 W
15 N

The information behind this is: 20 animals moved north, 40 northwest, 10 southwest and 10 west.

I would like to generate a chart like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoCh2.jpg) to visualize the movements.

**How can I do that using R?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the `radarchart` function of package **fmsb** helpful.

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(freq=c(5, 40, 10, 10, 15), 
  dir=c("N", "NW", "SW", "W", "N"))

# summarize by direction
dftot <- aggregate(freq ~ dir, df, sum)

# list of unique directions, starting at top and winding counterclockwise
uniqdir <- c("N", "NW", "W", "SW", "S", "SE", "E", "NE")

# arrange total counts in a matrix
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(dftot$freq[match(uniqdir, dftot$dir)], nrow=1, 
  dimnames=list(NULL, uniqdir)))
# replace missing values with zero
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
# add rows for maximum and minimums
df2 <- rbind(rep(max(df), length(uniqdir)), rep(0, length(uniqdir)), df)

# draw the plot
library(fmsb)
radarchart(df2, centerzero=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot!